# If condition help python

Tags: list, if-statement, maze

```
def cammino(L,inizio,fine,percorso):

    g=grafo(L)
    percorso=percorso+[inizio]
    #print(percorso)
    #set_stato(L,inizio,'V')
    if inizio==fine:
        return percorso
    if inizio not in L:
        print('Cella',inizio,'non presente')
        return None
    if fine not in L:
        print('Cella',fine,'non presente')
        return None
    for nodo in g[inizio]:
        if nodo not in percorso:
            #set_stato(L,nodo,'V')

            newpath=cammino(L,nodo,fine,percorso)
            if newpath:
                return newpath
    return []
```

Hi everyone, what does "if newpath:" means?
My newpath is a list. I don't understand what does the "if" do to a list

Comment: I meant newpath

Comment: I know that edit that in your question.

Comment: it checks whether the list is empty or not

Answer (score 1):

`if`, as elsewhere in Python, applied to a list tests if it's empty or not.

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = ["foo", "bar"]
>>> if a:
...     print a
... elif b:
...     print b
... 
['foo', 'bar']
```

This is true even if all of the elements of the list are falsy:

```
>>> c = [False]
>>> if c:
...     print "xyzzy"
... 
xyzzy
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#if) and [on truth testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) for more information.

Comment: I don't understand how it works in my case. that function finds a path between two cells of a maze. It returns the path, but "newpath" is created at each step of the for loop, so why it returns only the last created and not all the previous?

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal example that produces your error and what your error is? I can't reproduce what your issue is and am not entirely sure what you're asking.